# "Anoynmous methods" interesting behavior

Tags: java

I started off with this code, which did not compile:

```
Object[] obj= new Object[2];
obj[0]=new Object () { public String compute() {return "yay 1!";} };
obj[1]=new Object () { public String compute() {return "yay 2!";} };

for (Object o : obj)
    System.out.println(o.compute());
```

Because Object does not have a `compute()` method defined for it. So, I assumed that java threw away the function; however, the following did work:

```
Object[] obj= new Object[2];
obj[0]=new Object () { public String toString() {return "yay 1!";} };
obj[1]=new Object () { public String toString() {return "yay 2!";} };

for (Object o : obj)
    System.out.println(o);
```

So, java must still have the function definition stored somewhere, right?  Or is this because I'm overriding `toString()`?

My question is how do I tell java that `compute()` exists?

If it's not possible to do that, could I do something like overriding a method that does exist for Objects, as I did in the first example?  The method that `compute()` actually stands for is a method that takes an `int`. This may be horrible, but should I override `wait(long l)`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second works because `toString` is one of `Object`'s methods...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java did not "throw away" the method; the instances you put into that array possess it, but Java's *type system* has no feature which would make them available to outside code.

You can verify the existence of the methods through reflection, for example.

If you want more methods for your anonymous classes, define an appropriate interface and use `new MyInterface() { ... }`.

Comment: The method that compute() actually stands in for is a method that takes an `int`. This may be horrible, but should I override `wait(long l)` to get this to work?

Comment: There would be no rationale to override `wait`.

Comment: @SteveP. If you really need a `compute` method, why don't you define an interface with that method and implement it as an anonymous local class?

Comment: Figured as much.  So if I define an interface and use `new MyInterface() { ... }`, it will tell java that the method(s) exist and I can call the method as I wanted to?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. The array must also be of type `MyInterface[]`.

Answer (score 1):

That's what is called Anonymous class

You defined an Anonymous class

```
new Object() { public String compute() {return "yay 1!";} }
```

which you couldn't use afterwards.

If you had declared

```
class Child { // extends Object {

  public String compute() {return "yay 1!";}

}
```

then you could have done

```
for (Object o : obj)
    System.out.println(((Child)o).compute());
```